# Make google pixel look like samsung?

Tags: samsung, google-pixel

I have a google pixel 6a, I was wondering if I can make it look like a samsung android phone (like a samsung galaxy user interface)?
Like instead of scrolling down make it have multiple "pages of apps" or give it a "back" button

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizontal app drawer can be obtained using a custom launcher e.g. give [Microsoft Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.launcher&hl=en_IN&gl=US) a try

Navigation Buttons instead of Navigation Gestures can be obtained using these steps

- Head into the Settings app and select Settings > Gestures to find a bevy of gesture-related options.
- Once in the Gestures menu, tap on System Navigation to choose between gestures and a three-button navigation system.
- Select 3-Button Navigation to activate the Go back, Home, and switch apps buttons.

Hope this helps!